# Editable HTML table with @Html.DropDownListFor field in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create HTML table page in .net MVC which has editable fields. I can do this for TextBoxFor fields. On submit of page Post controller method receives values from table. I face problem when I use DropDownListFor. Page is rendering with DropDownListFor fields but on submit the post controller method receives Model object without any data in its properties. In below code snippet SaveMyItems controller action method do receives Model object with null values set to its properties.

**This is my Model Classes**

```
public class ItemsEntryModel
{
  public ItemModel Item { get; set; }
  public List<MyItemOptions> MyItemsOptionList { get; set; }  
  //individual field of HTML table      
}

public class ItemModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class MyItemOptions
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int MyItemOptionUniqueNo { get; set; }
  public string OptionName { get; set; }
  public MyItemSubOptions SelectedItemSubOption { get; set; }
  public List<MyItemSubOptions> MyItemSubOptionsList { get; set; } 
  //bind in individual dropdown of field
}

public class MyItemSubOptions
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string SubOptionName {get; set;}
}
```

**Java Script Code to Call Controlller action method to render partial view and submit partial view**

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/MyItemsPartialView',
    contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        Id: data
    },
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function (result) {
    //result of MyItemsPartialView action method is displayed in partial view
});

$.post('/MyController/SaveMyItems', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
    
    //response of SaveMyItems action method is displayed on main view
});
```

```html
@model ItemsEntryModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12 mb-4">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @Model.Item.ItemName
        </div>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover bg-inverse-warning">
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.MyItemsOptionList)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OptionName)
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.MyItemsOptionList)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.SelectedItemSubOption, new SelectList(item.MyItemSubOptionsList, "ID", "Name"), new { @id = "Product_" + item.MyItemOptionUniqueNo, @class = "form-control" })
                        <input id="lblMyItemOptionUniqueNo" type="hidden" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyItemOptionUniqueNo)" />
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just a guess: have you tried adding name to your hidden input field? Because MVC model binding happens on name...

Comment: Name property sets to name="item.SelectedItemSubOption" for all dropdownlist in each column even after setting @name = "Product_" + tem.MyItemOptionUniqueNo

Comment: My best guess is you're using `SelectedItemSubOption` to bind with dropdownlist which declared as complex object; while your option lists set ID as value from `MyItemSubOptionsList`. Why not just bound to `MyItemOptionUniqueNo` (and remove the hidden field)?